# htaccess replacing one folder to another

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to change all the calls from **example.com/files/** to **example.com/app/files/** with out any redirection( URL redirection ).

calls maybe contain sub directories and css , js , png , jpg files.

like.

**example.com/files/css/style.css**

**example.com/files/js/script.js**

**example.com/files/image/background.png**

**example.com/files/upload/prof/1.jpg**

In the same time i needed to add this code too( codeigniter index.php removel ).

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you clarify bit more like what URL do you want to display in browser for both static and non-static files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your htaccess should look like this

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^files/(.+)$ /app/files/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```